# style that does not work on Apple devices

Tags: css, webkit

i have a website html and css
i have a icon ( SVG )
and i add effect :

-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(-4px 5px 6px #0000008c);
OR
drop-shadow(-4px 5px 6px #0000008c);

the effect work on all device except ios devices

i try that

```
        box-sizing: border-box;
        box-shadow: -4px 5px 6px #0000008c;
        filter: drop-shadow(-4px 5px 6px #0000008c);
        -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(-4px 5px 6px #0000008c);
        -moz-filter: drop-shadow(-4px 5px 6px #0000008c);
        -ms-filter: drop-shadow(-4px 5px 6px #0000008c);
        -o-filter: drop-shadow(-4px 5px 6px #0000008c);
          transition: filter 0.1s ease-in;
         -webkit-transition: filter 0.1s ease-in;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this minimal working example
https://codepen.io/homie_veroni/pen/rNPjjGK

```
<div class="icon">
  <svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-check-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
  <path d="M10.97 4.97a.235.235 0 0 0-.02.022L7.477 9.417 5.384 7.323a.75.75 0 0 0-1.06 1.06L6.97 11.03a.75.75 0 0 0 1.079-.02l3.992-4.99a.75.75 0 0 0-1.071-1.05z"/>
</svg>
</div>

#svg {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    border-radius:100%;
    box-shadow: -4px 5px 6px #0000008c;
    filter: drop-shadow(-4px 5px 6px #0000008c);
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(-4px 5px 6px #0000008c);
    -moz-filter: drop-shadow(-4px 5px 6px #0000008c);
    -ms-filter: drop-shadow(-4px 5px 6px #0000008c);
    -o-filter: drop-shadow(-4px 5px 6px #0000008c);
   }
```